# Is stock in a company considered a good or a service, or something else?

Tags: stocks, accounting

I'm trying to classify what stock is on a website I've been working on in my spare time. I have two options in my database right now:

1. Goods
2. Services

I wanted to add this entry for Facebook stock:

http://www.settingprice.com/stocks/3/price-of-facebook-stock/

and I wasn't sure if I should call it a good or a service, or should I create a new a category called "Stocks", "Equity", or something else?

Comment: asset, generally.

Comment: @littleadv ah, I like that. Would things like homes and cars be considered assets too, or are those goods?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your definition for "goods" is... If its an accounting question then yes, these are assets (or inventory, if you're a realtor or a car dealer).

Comment: This question is a perfect fit for the Accounting site (currently a proposal in Area 51: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113560/accounting?referrer=FNOG9_mXNYnhlAdnl9FE8w2 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on whether or not your differentiating against. If its capital stock or stock as in a share certificate in the company. If its a share in the company then in my opinion using Equity would be best as it is a form of an asset and does refer to a piece of ownership of the entity. I wouldn't consider a share of stock a service, since the service to you is say Facebook or the broker who facilitates the transaction of buying or selling FB stock. I also would not consider it a Capital Good, as the Capital Good's would be the referring to the actual capital like the servers,other computer equipments etc.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook the company is probably better understood as a *capital good* - it is a collection of software and servers and a well-known brand name with a snazzy network effect under reasonably competent corporate governance that can produce final goods and services (mostly services) that actually have value. A share of Facebook stock is a share of ownership in that capital.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_good

which makes some concessions for the difference between capital goods and capital services, so it's kind of a fuzzy thing.

Answer (score 0):

Stock is ownership. And whether the thing you own is a good or service irrelevant. The ownership itself is all that matters.

Ownership = service ???
Ownership = good ???

Maybe the problem is your trying to fit a verb into a noun-based categories?